# On hover, I don't see my div sliding down with auto height of the parents

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a menu with dropdowns. On hover, I want a div with ID slider to slide down and have it take the height of the parent

This is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/UzzAT/1/

```
#nav ul.subs {
    color: #333333;
    display: none;
    left: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: 96%;
    /*padding-left:50%;
    margin-left:-405px;*/
    z-index: 9606;
}
```

Comment: `id`'s should be unique on their respective page. There are several `#slider`'s in this document.

Comment: can you please guide and tell me a smarter way

Comment: Learn HTML and use classes

Comment: You really don't want more than element with the same id. You don't want to put "this" in quotes. Chances are your problem is associated with the fact that the transitions in the CSS have not completed. You might be inclined to write it all in jquery as opposed to mixing in with css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an action applied to multiple items you should use classes.

Also, you should do the stretch animation inside the mouse enter function.

```
$("#nav").mouseenter(function () {
    var $stretch = $(".slider");
    $stretch.animate({ height: $stretch.parent().height() }, 500 );
    $("this").find('.slider').stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
});

$("#nav").mouseleave(function () {
    var $stretch = $(".slider");
    $stretch.animate({ height: 0 }, 500 );        
    $("this").find('.slider').stop(true,true).slideUp(500);
});
```

Alternatively, put the ULs inside the slider DIVs instead of using it like a strange mask.

Comment: I have updated my fiddle but how can i strect the div to auto height of the subs http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/UzzAT/2/

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do now, check this post for help.  You want to get the height of the UL, set it to the div and then slide the div out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680001/why-do-the-ul-elements-have-no-height

Comment: updated the answer.  Why don't you just put the menu items inside the slider divs?

Comment: i can't because I want the sub to be 100% width and the drop down should be relative. It means the droplink links should come below respective links and not start from extreme left

Comment: Makes sense, in any case, the modified slider function should work.

Comment: Are you building this dynamically? Why not use the Divs to position the menus where they need to be or even based on where the supermenu is using jquery rather than depending on HTML

Comment: but how to handle them dynamically as this is CMS based in php

Comment: get the position of $(this)and position based on that

Comment: Something like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JPvya/ you want to get the values of the overed over element, rather than the mouse click and adjust for height and width.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it could be done.

First, Remove every :hover statment in your CSS.

Then, i add the following jQuery:

```
$("#nav li").not('.subs li').mouseenter(function () {


    if ($(".slider").is(":visible")) {

        $(".slider").stop(false, false).animate({
            height: $(this).find('.subs').height() + "px"
        }, 500)
        $(this).find('.subs').show();
    } else {

        var subHeight = $(this).find('.subs').height();
        $(".slider").css({
            "height": subHeight + "px"
        })
        $(".slider").stop(false, false).slideDown(500);
        $(this).find('.subs').show();
    }

})

$("#nav li").mouseleave(function () {

    $(this).find('.subs').hide();
})

$("#nav").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".slider").stop(false, true).delay(500).slideUp(500);
})
```

I add IF in order to check if the slider have to be displayed, or only animated.
I also add a mouseleave handler for #nav to prevend your slider from jumping between items. 
And delay() was added for smooth animation.

I also change the css :

```
#nav ul.subs {
    color: #333333;
    display: none;
    left: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 96%;
    z-index: 9606;
}
```

Have a look at the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zP3ZD/)**